How do I fix an 'AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute '_get_save_spec' in Python
This code produces error 'AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute '_get_save_spec':
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.models.load_model("../mymodel.keras")
model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.save('saved_model.keras')

model = tf.keras.models.load_model('saved_model.keras')
model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
             loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics= 
             ['accuracy'])

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
tflite_model = converter.convert()

Error:
AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute '_get_save_spec'

I didn't correct answer for my code.

HI, is it still relevant? Could you share/upload file with the model somewhere? Also could you please share versions of tensorflow, keras and tflite that you are using?. It seems that the error is very specific to the model and your keras, tensorflow and tflite versions.

I had the same error while converting to onnx and the problem was I didn't include input_signature in  tf2onnx.convert.from_keras function

@Audida Did you find the solution for this, I am facing the same issue
